# PHP CodeIgniter returning Controller Name rather than Doctrine Associated Entity

Tags: php, orm, controller, doctrine, entity

I have a basic entity that has a `Unidirectional OneToOne` relationship with another entity.  I have an instance of the owning entity that's created via a variable method as so:

```
$entity = new $entity;
```

where `$entity` on the right-hand side is simply a string that describes the class.  When I grab the inverse entity (an `Address`) from the owning entity it returns a class of the same type as the controller I'm using.

```
$object = $entity->getAddress();
```

this line of code returns an object of type `Ajax` (the controller this code is in in CodeIgniter).  The code for the getter is simple, nothing fancy:

```
public function getAddress() {
    return $this->address;
}
```

What could possibly be going on here?  Why would I be getting back an instance of my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is $this->address set as?

Is it possibly that you setting `$this->address = $this`?

Because if `$this->address = $this` then

```
$object = $entity->getAddress();
```

is really

```
$object = $entity;
```

which of course is an object of type $entity;

Comment: Oh man, I'm an idiot.  I'm attempting to create a new entity here so obviously none of the associated entities would be created yet...and that's what I'm trying to retrieve.  Thanks for helping me see that.  Hopefully that's the problem!